# ProgressBar is not showing

Tags: android, progress-bar, android-videoview

I want the progressBar to return until I have `VideoView.setOnPreparedListener` but the `ProgressBar` is definitely not showing up. It only appears when VideoView visibility is gone. `VideoView.setOnPreparedListener` doesn't work in this case either.

I looked at the previously asked questions but it didn't meet my needs. Is there a mistake in my layout design?

**Layout:**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <VideoView
        android:id="@+id/video_loader"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:gravity="center" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progress"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:indeterminateTint="@color/colorAccent"
        android:elevation="10dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:indeterminate="true"/>

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon_video_play"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_baseline_play_circle_filled_24" />

     <com.android.android.video.view.VideoTimelineView
        android:id="@+id/videoTimeLine"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp" />
          
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/videoInfoView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="26dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="26dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="110dp"
        android:background="@drawable/grey_rect"
        android:padding="7dp"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="@dimen/kod"
        android:visibility="gone"
        tools:text="0:42 | 7.2 mb"
        tools:visibility="visible" />

    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/handlerTop"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:max="1000"
        android:paddingTop="9dp"
        android:progressDrawable="@android:color/transparent"
        android:secondaryProgress="0"
        android:splitTrack="false"
        tools:progress="1000"
        tools:thumb="@drawable/vertical_line" />

</FrameLayout>
```

**Code:**

```
  ProgressBar progressBar = findViewById(R.id.progress);
  progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

  ImageView playView = findViewById(R.id.icon_video_play);
  playView.setVisibility(View.GONE);

  VideoView mVideoView = findViewById(R.id.videoView);
  mVideoView.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                playView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        });
```

Comment: I have faced this issue, as well though in other Views ofcourse. This is the same case with material `CircularProgressIndicator` as well as `LinearProgressIndicator`. The visibility stuff on the `ProgressBar` seems to be causing weird issues. Upvoted!